# how to get the variables from the configuration file?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem for python2.7 / django1.6.

I need a console to display the value of the variable SITE_ID of the file settings.py. For this I use the command:

```
python manage.py shell
```

but what to do I do not know.

Comment: from django.conf import settings print settings.SITE_ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the settings:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> print(settings.SITE_ID)
```